# Flutter Firestore Stream error "as required by the closure's context."

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I'm getting the following error not sure why `The return type 'List<DogModel>' isn't a 'DogModel', as required by the closure's context.`

Here is my Firestore service file where I get the Stream

```
Stream<DogModel> getDogs(String uid) {
return dogCollection.where('userId', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots().map(
      (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
          .map((document) => DogModel.fromFire(document))
          .toList(),
    );
```

}

Here is my model

```
part 'dog_model.g.dart';

enum DogGender {
  male,
  female,
}
enum DogWeight {
  kg,
  lbs,
}

enum DogStatus {
  active,
  training,
  injured,
  retired,
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class DogModel {
  String? dogImage;
  String dogName;
  DogBreed? breedInfo;
  @JsonKey(fromJson: dateTimeFromTimestamp, toJson: dateTimeAsIs)
  DateTime? dogBirthday;
  double? dogWeight;
  DogWeight? weightType;
  DogGender? dogGender;
  List<String>? dogType;
  DogStatus? dogStatus;
  bool? registered;
  String? dogChipId;
  @JsonKey(fromJson: dateTimeFromTimestamp, toJson: dateTimeAsIs)
  DateTime? createdAt;
  DogStats? dogStats;
  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  String? id;
  String? userId;

  DogModel({
    required this.dogImage,
    required this.dogName,
    required this.breedInfo,
    required this.dogBirthday,
    required this.dogWeight,
    required this.weightType,
    required this.dogGender,
    required this.dogType,
    required this.dogStatus,
    required this.registered,
    this.dogStats,
    this.dogChipId,
    this.createdAt,
    this.userId,
    this.id,
  });

  factory DogModel.fromFire(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return DogModel.fromJson(snapshot as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }

  // JsonSerializable constructor
  factory DogModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$DogModelFromJson(json);

  // Serialization
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DogModelToJson(this);
}
```

If I do  `Stream<Object>` its fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDogs` function body is returning a `List<DogModel>` but the function definition is `Stream<DogModel>`. So change the definition to `Stream<List<DogModel>>` as follow:

```dart
// fix this   ↓
Stream<List<DogModel>> getDogs(String uid) {
return dogCollection.where('userId', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots().map(
      (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
          .map((document) => DogModel.fromFire(document))
          .toList(), // <~~~~ you're returning a list here 
    );
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it but how would I then call the stream 

I have 

StreamProvider<Object>(
          create: (context) =>
              DogFirestoreService().getDogs('GeVnAbdq9BWs1STbytlAU65qkbc2'),
          initialData: 10,
          child: const DogsListScreen(),
        ),

Comment: You can call it like this: `StreamProvider<List<DogModel>>( create: (context) => DogFirestoreService().getDogs('GeVnAbdq9BWs1STbytlAU65qkbc2'), initialData: 10, child: const DogsListScreen(), )`

Comment: I deleted my comment, it was wrong. @Mayank is correct. Though,  I'm not sure why you've `initialData: 10` .. it's not the same type.  you should make it empty list (e.g. `[]` ) unless you've a list of `DogModel` to pass as initialData.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I'm having a hard time with Streams, the 10 was my mistake. This looks good now but when I call the stream in the child I'm getting "type '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast" I'm doing this "final test = context.watch<List<DogModel>>();"

Comment: I take it something with the model to json

Comment: @Almog .. try `DogModel.fromFire(document.data)`

Comment: The argument type 'Object? Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>'

Comment: Maybe it's `document.data()`-- try to inspect the object -- haven't used firestore for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the return type of method `getDogs()` as `Stream<DogModel>` whereas your method returns `Stream<List<DogModel>>`, that is, it return a `List` of `DogModel`s. So your `getDogs()` method declaration should be like this:

```dart
Stream<<List<DogModel>> getDogs(String uid) {
  ...
}
```