# Flutter Firestore with Streams getting type '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype' error?

Tags: firebase, flutter, provider

I'm getting the following error when trying to work with Firestore and Stream Provider

```
type '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
```

Here is my root page

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthProvider, DogProvider>(
      update: (context, value, previous) => DogProvider(), // ..getDogList()
      create: (_) => DogProvider(), //..getDogList()
    ),
    StreamProvider<Object>(
      create: (context) =>
          DogFirestoreService().getDogs('GeVnAbdq9BWs1STbytlAU65qkbc2'),
      initialData: 10,
      child: const DogsListScreen(),
    ),
```

My Firestore Service getting the stream

```
Stream<List<DogModel>> getDogs(String uid) {
return dogCollection.where('userId', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots().map(
      (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
          .map((document) => DogModel.fromFire(document))
          .toList(),
    );
```

}

The model

```
 @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class DogModel {
  String? dogImage;
  String dogName;
  DogBreed? breedInfo;
  @JsonKey(fromJson: dateTimeFromTimestamp, toJson: dateTimeAsIs)
  DateTime? dogBirthday;
  double? dogWeight;
  DogWeight? weightType;
  DogGender? dogGender;
  List<String>? dogType;
  DogStatus? dogStatus;
  bool? registered;
  String? dogChipId;
  @JsonKey(fromJson: dateTimeFromTimestamp, toJson: dateTimeAsIs)
  DateTime? createdAt;
  DogStats? dogStats;
  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  String? id;
  String? userId;

  DogModel({
    required this.dogImage,
    required this.dogName,
    required this.breedInfo,
    required this.dogBirthday,
    required this.dogWeight,
    required this.weightType,
    required this.dogGender,
    required this.dogType,
    required this.dogStatus,
    required this.registered,
    this.dogStats,
    this.dogChipId,
    this.createdAt,
    this.userId,
    this.id,
  });

  factory DogModel.fromFire(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return DogModel.fromJson(snapshot as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }

  // JsonSerializable constructor
  factory DogModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$DogModelFromJson(json);

  // Serialization
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DogModelToJson(this);
}
```

And in the widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final test = context.watch<Object>();
print(test);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640272/10976714), you need to extract the data from the document as follow:

```dart
Stream<List<DogModel>> getDogs(String uid) {
return dogCollection.where('userId', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots().map(
      (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
          .map((document) => DogModel.fromJson(document.data()) // <~~ here
          .toList(),
    );
```

As you see, you should call `document.data()` (not `document.data`, which was my mistake earlier).

Comment: Yes I did that the issue is with factory DogModel.fromFire "type '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast" 

I think I need to copy the keys but not how

Comment: @Almog did you try `DogModel.fromJson(document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)` instead of of `DogModel.fromFire`? .. something weird happening there :/

Comment: Wow that was it, I think its good now

Comment: @Almog I don't think you even need the `as Map<String, dynamic>` cast btw..

Comment: The quick question around best practices, I have my Firestore service file and provider which is separated for adding dogs, update everything goes the provider but for the stream, it's directly to firestore class is that correct? 

And second, should I only be calling the stream inside the correct widget not the root

Comment: @Almog 1-you can create an abstract class (e.g. `DogQueries`) and inside it you put the methods that is used in the app (e.g. `Stream<List<DogModel>> getDogs();`). Then create an implementation for that class specific to firestore (`DogQueriesFirestore`). This helps so even if you wanna change the database later, you just create a new implementation. 

2-, I believe `StreamProvider` will handle the subscription correctly. As long as the tree above it is not changing, so it'll not create a new subscription after each build. So just place it as high as necessary in the widget tree.

Comment: @Almog The only case, that I can think of, where you need to place it at the root is when the `StreamProvider` is needed at multiple pages (because when you navigate to pages, you navigate from the root widget).

Comment: Yes what I thought I don't think it needs to be in the root I have the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider in the and not even sure that is correct